# Pandas set value range of cell with list

Tags: python, pandas

So I tried playing around with multiple options to set values of multiple cells in Pandas using a list but not able to get the right results. Searched here and on Google with no luck.
Here is my sample df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PersonID':['AB-123', 'AB-123', 'AB-123', 'AB-123', 'AB-123'],
'Date':['2/1/2016', '2/2/2016', '2/3/2016', '2/4/2016', '2/5/2016']})
df['Score']=''
```

I am triying to add value in middle of the 'Score' column and tried following ways;

Option 1: Using set_value

```
df = df.set_value([3:5],'Score',[3,4,5])
```

Doesn't work because of the slicing and the list of values.

Option 2:

```
df.loc[3:5,'Score']=[3,4,5]
```

same problem as above

Option 3:

```
df[df.index[3:5]]['Score']=[3,4,5]
```

None of the above methods works. Does anyone know anyway that this could work out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you need this, by using `numpy.r_`

```
import numpy as np
df.loc[np.r_[2:5],'Score']=[3,4,5]
df
Out[307]: 
       Date PersonID  Score
0  2/1/2016   AB-123    NaN
1  2/2/2016   AB-123    NaN
2  2/3/2016   AB-123    3.0
3  2/4/2016   AB-123    4.0
4  2/5/2016   AB-123    5.0
```

Comment: Even df.loc[2:4,'Score']=[3,4,5] works. I like np.r_ :)

Answer (score 2):

You can let pandas handle indexing alignment for you.

```
df['Score'] = pd.Series([3, 4, 5], index=np.r_[2:5])
df

       Date PersonID  Score
0  2/1/2016   AB-123    NaN
1  2/2/2016   AB-123    NaN
2  2/3/2016   AB-123    3.0
3  2/4/2016   AB-123    4.0
4  2/5/2016   AB-123    5.0
```

`np.r_` is used to the same effect here as in Wen's answer. Note; you do not need to pre-initialise `df['Score'] = ''` as you are currently doing if you use this method.

Comment: `df[np.r_[2:5],'Score'] = pd.Series([3, 4, 5], index=np.r_[2:5])` if you don't want other rows to become NaN.